# Incorrect loss value for binary classification and loss not changing in pytorch training loop?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I am trying to perform a forward training loop for a binary classification task, however, the initial value of the CrossEntropyLoss() torch function is incorrect (supposed to be ~.69) and does not change during training. Here's my setup:

Network:

```
class my_network(nn.Module):

def __init__(self, config):
    super(my_network, self).__init__()
    self.num_labels = config.num_labels
    self.config = config

    self.classifier = nn.Sequential(
        nn.Linear(512, 256, bias=True),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Dropout(p=config.dropout, inplace=False),
        nn.Linear(256, 128, bias=True),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Dropout(p=config.dropout, inplace=False),
        nn.Linear(128, 64, bias=True),
        nn.BatchNorm1d(1),
        nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
        nn.Linear(64,2, bias=True),
    )

def forward(self, inputs, labels=None):
    logits = self.classifier(inputs)
    return logits
```

now for the training loop:

```
nn_model = my_network(config)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4,weight_decay=5e-3) #  L2 regularization
loss_fct= nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

nn_model.train()
for epoch in range(2):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    running_loss = 0.0
    for i, data in enumerate(tqdm(train_loader)):
        # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
        inputs, labels = data['embeddings'], data['labels'].float()
        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = nn_model(inputs)
        loss = loss_fct(outputs.view(-1, 2), labels.view(-1))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        running_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 2000 == 1999:    # print every 2000 
            print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                  (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
            running_loss = 0.0
```

All I get is .735 loss throughout, and it does not change much. What am I doing wrong? The data here is of shape (batch_size, 512)

Comment: how is your data distributed across labels: is it 50/50 split between the two labels?

Comment: have you tried changing the learning rate? have you considered using `BatchNorm` layers? what happens if you try shallower network?

Comment: *"the initial value of the CrossEntropyLoss() torch function is incorrect (supposed to be ~.69)"* your first `print` occurs at `i = 1999` and not at `i = 0` ...

Comment: @Ivan yep, I checked the loss at the first step, it is the same. It is not changing at all.

Comment: @Shai I am using batchnorm at the last layer. I will try using a shallower network and change the learning rate and update this post. Also, my data is not balanced, would that skew the results?

Comment: BCE is ~0.69 for balanced data, when the split is ~45% then BCE loss of 0.735 is expected.

Comment: I see, and what about the loss not going down. Any idea why this might be happening? I will try using another learning rate, but it does not make sense why it wouldn't be going down tbh.

Comment: You should first try to overfit your data by reducing the number of elements in your training set. This will show if your model is learning, then you can work from there.